# Get text from Alert to compare with string - Cucumber + Capybara + Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I need to get the text that appears in the alert to compare with a text string that was expected by the Test.

I'm using Cucumber + Ruby + rspec and Capybara.

**I have tried the following:**

```
Then(/^I see the message "([^"]*)"$/) do |mensagemsucesso|

    TextAlert = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text
    sleep(5)
    Expect(textAlert).to eql mensagemsucesso

End
```

**Error:**

> No modal dialog is currently open
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchAlertError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about modal system alerts triggered by JS `alert`, `confirm`, `prompt` then you need to use the capybara methods `accept_alert`, `accept_confirm`, `dismiss_confirm`, `accept_prompt` or `dismiss_prompt` - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#accept_alert-instance_method

All of these will return the text the modal showed, or you can pass in a string which will be tested against the text of the modal and raise an error if it doesn't match.  They also need to take a block that has the action that triggers the modal, so if clicking a link triggered it your step could be something like

```
When /^(?:|I ) click "([^"]*)" and accept "([^"]*)"$/ do |link, msg|
  accept_alert msg do
    click_link(link)
  end
end
```